# Which payment method use for US Doller and INR (Indian rupies) in magento 2.2.x?

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.2.4

I have create 2 store and 2 different currency like US Doller and INR. So i want to create one payment method to use both of store in magento 2.Please give me suggest which payment method use.

Comment: You have to set same payment method store wise.You have to first select store from admin and than set the payment method:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any payment methods which are available in Magento 2 by default but if you are looking for professional and secure payment gateway than you can also find many payment extensions out there.

https://www.rootways.com/shop/magento-2-stripe-payment-extension

here check this extension. it will help you in your efforts.

Comment: which payment method use for user friendly

Comment: @Devidas the one i have recommended is also an user friendly although it is depending upon your choice and your websites' user group weather you want free or professional payment method. I recommend you go with professional methods because they are more user friendly than other ones

Answer (score 0):

There are several payment methods available in Magento 2 that can be used for multiple stores with different currencies. One such method is PayPal, which supports multiple currencies and can be easily configured for both US Dollar and INR.

Another option is to use Stripe, which also supports multiple currencies and can be configured to work with both US Dollar and INR: https://marketplace.magento.com/magenest-module-stripe-global.html

You can also consider using a payment gateway like Authorize.net, which supports multiple currencies and can be used for multiple stores. However, you may need to check if the gateway supports the currencies you want to use.

Ultimately, the choice of payment method will depend on your specific requirements and the compatibility of the module with your Magento version and store setup. It is recommended to do thorough research and testing before selecting a payment method.